# inconsistent results using golang channels

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I a task written in Go to get a unique list from a bunch of text files. I put in some parallelization using channels and am having inconsistent results now - a variance of 5 records output/not output each time with the same input files.

The am testing it with `go run process.go | wc -l` on Fedora x86_64, go1.1.2, 8 core amd.

The code is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "io"    
    "encoding/csv"
    "regexp"
    "log"
)

var (
    cleanRe *regexp.Regexp = regexp.MustCompile("[^0-9]+")
    comma rune ='\t'
    fieldsPerRecord=-1
)

func clean(s string) string {
    clean:=cleanRe.ReplaceAllLiteralString(s,"")
    if len(clean)<6 {return ""}
    return clean
}

func uniqueChannel(inputChan chan []string, controlChan chan string) {
    defer func(){controlChan<-"Input digester."}()
    uniq:=make(map[string]map[string]bool)
    i:=0
    for record:= range inputChan {
        i++
        id,v:=record[0],record[1]
        if uniq[id]==nil {
            uniq[id]=make(map[string]bool)
        } else if !uniq[id][v] {
            uniq[id][v]=true
            fmt.Println(id,string(comma),v)
        }
    }
    log.Println("digest ", i)
}

func processFile(fileName string, outputChan chan []string, controlChan chan string) {
    defer func(){controlChan<-fileName}()
    f,err:=os.Open(fileName)
    if err!=nil{log.Fatal(err)}
    r:=csv.NewReader(f)
    r.FieldsPerRecord = fieldsPerRecord
    r.Comma = comma

    //  Process the records
    i:=0
    for record,err:=r.Read();err!=io.EOF;record,err=r.Read() {
        if err!=nil{continue}
        id:=record[0]
        for _,v:=range record[1:] {
            if cleanV:=clean(v);cleanV!=""{
                i++
                outputChan<-[]string{id,cleanV}
            }
        }
    }
    log.Println(fileName,i)
}


func main() {
    inputs:=[]string{}
    recordChan:=make(chan []string,100)
    processesLeft:=len(inputs)+1
    controlChan:=make(chan string,processesLeft)

    //  Ingest the inputs
    for _,fName:=range inputs {
        go processFile(fName,recordChan,controlChan)
    }

    //  This is the loop to ensure it's all unique
    go uniqueChannel(recordChan,controlChan)

    //  Make sure all the channels close up
    for processesLeft>0 {
        if processesLeft==1{
            close(recordChan)
        }
        c:=<-controlChan
        log.Println(c)
        processesLeft--
    }
    close(controlChan)
}
```

It seems like it closes the channel before it's empty and quite. Without the closing mechanism I was getting deadlocks - I'm out of ideas.

Comment: If you could strip down the code to some easy digestible form, maybe even runnable on the playground it would be much easier to help.  Otherwise: You may try using a sync.Waitgroup which might be much easier than lots of control channels. Other option: Run under the race detector to see if you have some data race which would case this inconsistencies.

Comment: I had a look and cannot see anything wrong with your code.  Could you post the input files which cause the problems somewhere?  Also, when it goes wrong, do all goroutines report themselves finished via the control channel?  Is there any special significance to the number 5 (i.e. is this the number of input files or CPUs)?

Comment: If you change the `if err!=nil{continue}` bit in `processFile` to log the error, does that shed any light on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ditch the control channel and use a `sync.WaitGroup`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "sync"
)

var (
    cleanRe         *regexp.Regexp = regexp.MustCompile("[^0-9]+")
    comma           rune           = '\t'
    fieldsPerRecord                = -1
)

func clean(s string) string {
    clean := cleanRe.ReplaceAllLiteralString(s, "")
    if len(clean) < 6 {
        return ""
    }
    return clean
}

func uniqueChannel(inputChan chan []string) {
    uniq := make(map[string]map[string]bool)
    i := 0
    for record := range inputChan {
        i++
        id, v := record[0], record[1]
        if uniq[id] == nil {
            uniq[id] = make(map[string]bool)
        } else if !uniq[id][v] {
            uniq[id][v] = true
            fmt.Println(id, string(comma), v)
        }
    }
    log.Println("digest ", i)
}

func processFile(fileName string, outputChan chan []string) {
    f, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    r := csv.NewReader(f)
    r.FieldsPerRecord = fieldsPerRecord
    r.Comma = comma

    //  Process the records
    for record, err := r.Read(); err != io.EOF; record, err = r.Read() {
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        id := record[0]
        for _, v := range record[1:] {
            if cleanV := clean(v); cleanV != "" {
                outputChan <- []string{id, cleanV}
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    inputs := []string{"ex.tsv"}
    recordChan := make(chan []string)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    //  Ingest the inputs
    for _, fName := range inputs {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            processFile(fName, recordChan)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(recordChan)
    }()

    //  This is the loop to ensure it's all unique
    uniqueChannel(recordChan)
}
```

Comment: I've since used this method and agree. Only change to mention is to defer the wg.Done().